# Django - How to pass a dictionary to a template tag

Tags: django, django-templates

I've created a custom template tag for rendering my form elements with the html attributes specified on the template. All I want to do is pass a dictionary to my tag as in:

```
{{ form.openid_identifier|htmlattributes:{'class' : 'something', 'id': 'openid_identifier'} }}
```

Is there any way to write something like this on the template?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you're giving the syntax for a custom filter, not a custom tag. I'm going to answer the question assuming you meant to say custom filter.

Secondly, you cannot explicitly pass a dictionary to a filter (or a template tag, for that matter). Braces, brackets, and parentheses are not allowed as characters within `{% %}` and will result in a syntax error when parsing the template.

However, there is nothing to stop you from, for example, passing in a string that looks like a dictionary and then parsing it within the template tag:

```
{{ form.openid_identifier|htmlattributes:"{'class' : 'something', 'id': 'openid_identifier'}" }}
```

In this case, your custom filter would need to correctly parse this as a dictionary.

It might be helpful to know why you're using the solution your are using. I'd normally set the class for a Form object from within the form class (usually in `forms.py`). Or, if you wanted more exact control over the tag in question, just go ahead and spell it out:

```
<input type="text" name="openid_identifier" id="openid_identifier" class="something" />
```

Comment: I just looked at your [very related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4951810/django-how-to-add-html-attributes-to-forms-on-templates) so I suppose that answers why you're not interested in using the form class. In which case, writing out the HTML manually is, in my opinion, better, clearer, and more concise than using the filter.

Comment: Parsing a string that looks like a dictionary was indeed the easiest solution for me.

Answer (score 0):

By takes_context = True and pass the data you need from the view.